# What exactly are sample elements from a population?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, expected-value

If there is a sample with sequence $ x_1 , x_2 , ... , x_n$ for example, that is taken randomly from a population, what exactly are these elements $ x_1 , x_2 , ... , x_n$? What do they represent? Every time I search for an explanation, all they do is take some numbers $ 2,5,3,1,6,3$ for example and estimate the mean $\mu$  of the population, but what do these elements $ 2,5,3,1,6,3$ represent?

I'm asking this question because I'm trying to prove the expected value of the sample mean $\bar x$

$ \bar x = \frac {\sum x_i}{n} = \frac {x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n}{n}$

$E( \bar x) = \frac {1}{n} [E(x_1) + E(x_2) + ... + E(x_n)]$

I'm stuck here because I don't know what $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ represent and what does it mean to take the expected value of them, I know each expected value of them should be equal to $\mu$ but I don't know why, hopefully someone enlightens me, thank you.

Comment: Your first sentence answers your question. They are $n$ values chosen randomly from the population.

Comment: Then what does it mean to take the expected value of a distinct number?

Comment: You can find that in any Probability textbook. Another way to find out would be [here](https://www.google.com/).

Comment: These $x_i$ are the observations you make in your sample, and these all came from some underlying distribution with mean $\mu$. Therefore we can expect any observation to be equal to $\mu$.

Comment: The graph of the population determines the mean by adding all the data and divide by the number of points $N$ , that's how we get $ \mu$ , but when we take a subset of the population, that is the sample, we can calculate $ \bar x$ , but how can we calculate the mean of $ \bar x $ without a distribution?

Comment: The sample mean $\overline X$ has a probability distribution of its own (the sampling distribution). In any case, $E(\overline X)$ should make sense as the expected value of the random variable $\overline X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lecturer wants to know the average age of the people in a large auditorium.  It's obviously impractical to ask everyone his age age, so he selects $10$ people at random and asks them their ages.  The $10$ people chosen are the elements of a random sample.  The average of their ages is the sample mean.

**EDIT**

Suppose we have a set of $1000$ distinct integers.  We select $10$ integers at random and compute their average.  The $10$ integers chosen are the elements of the sample, and their average is the sample mean.  But we could perform this experiment again, choosing another random sample of $10$ numbers (after replacing the first sample) and computing their average.  Say we do this repeatedly.  Each time we do this, we get a value of a random variable $X.$  You are being asked to show that $E(X)$ is the average of all the numbers in the population, so that taking the sample mean is actually a reasonable way of estimating the population average.

In answer to your second comment, $x_1$ is a random variable whose value is the first number selected at random, so it makes perfect sense to ask for its expectation.  When we say $x_1=3$ we mean that in a particular experiment, the first number selected was $3,$ not that $x_1$ is a symbol representing the integer $3.$

Comment: That's nice, suppose the set $x_i$ $ i = 0,1,2..,10$ are the ages we collected, and I can calculate the sample mean $ \bar x$ , now how can I get the expected value of the sample mean? Normally when we take the expected value of a discrete random variable, it's $E(x) = \sum x_i f(x_i)$ , but in my question, $x_i$ are just single numbers, how can I take the expectation?

Comment: @cazanova I'm not entirely sure I understand you, but I'll edit my answer to try to explain this.

Comment: In this equation: $E( \bar x) = \frac {1}{n} [E(x_1) + E(x_2) + ... + E(x_{10})]$

You said these $x_i$ will represent a random sample of the ages.
In this context, what is $E(x_1) , E(x_2) , ...$ ?
To evaluate them, they are supposed to be random variables with probability distributions, but $x_i$ are just single elements taken from the population, if I'm missing something please inform me, thank you.

Comment: I understand now the logic, but only one problem left, how are we sure that $E(x_1) = E(x_2) .... = E(x_{10}) = \mu$ ? I'm sorry

Comment: That is what you are asked to prove.  But it's very simple.  Just use the formula you wrote down for the expectation in your first comment.

Comment: I don't know if I'm over complicating things, but this is what I got:

$E(x_1) = \sum (x_1)_i f((x_1)_i) = (x_1)_1 f((x_1)_1) + ... + (x_1)_n f((x_1)_n)$
$E(x_2) =  \sum (x_2)_i f((x_2)_i) = (x_2)_1 f((x_2)_1) + ... + (x_2)_n f((x_2)_n)$  and so on to $E(x_n)$

I thought that since all sample elements are equally likely to occur, then $f((x_1)_i) = f((x_2)_i)$

Comment: Yes, that's right, and so the common value must be ????

Comment: $ \mu $ ofcourse, it was not clear at all at first, and it still is kind of abstract, but I understand this now, thank you.